# Do browser needs to download whole compressed page to start render it?

Tags: html, http, browser, gzip, web-frontend

As I know, when browser downloading uncompressed `index.html` it starts parsing and rendering it from stream. So you can see a part of a content even if you didn't receive the whole file.

The question: Will the browser work with compressed in `gzip` format html page as well as with plain html page? Or should it get the whole file, decompress it and then render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They can and do start decompressing immediately upon receipt of the first parcel of compressed data. At most a tens of bytes of compressed data at the end of the parcel is not decompressible until the next parcel arrives, and then only if you happen to be in a dynamic block header. Most of the time you are in the middle of a block, in which case only a few bits are not decompressible until you get the next parcel.